# How do output a long vertical file for behance?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize, artboard, behance

I was wondering how do people output high quality presentations that are extremely vertically long for Behance. I tried doing it in Illustrator, but the entire canvas wasn't large enough to encapsulate my artboard. I tried splitting it into two artboards, but couldn't join them up at output.

Answer (score 1):

Please share an example of "an extremely vertical long presentation". 
You can slice your long artboard into separate files (for example .jpg) and add them in order one after another. 

Example: create a 1920x5400 presentation, cut it into 5 .jpg files 1920x1080. Add them to the Behance project in order one after another and you have "an extremely vertical long presentation".

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, thank you so much, Slicing did the trick!